# SSH lag when accessing from outside

Tags: linux, networking, router, ssh

UPDATE: I just found out that the ssh command option(instead of an interactive shell that you just send a command with it) works somewhat.

example:

```
ssh pi@domainname ls
```

works and prints the content, but

```
ssh pi@domainname ls && echo hello
```

does only print the ls but not the echo it just gets stuck there

---

I have a weird problem. When I login to my raspberry pi within the local network via ssh it just works fine. But when I try to access it from outside it is showing the password pop up and if entered the login message with the last login aso. but the shell won't show up. It takes about 10 to 30 minutes until a connection is established and then I can enter up to 4 commands before it freezes again.

now I thought it would be the raspberry pi fault but the same goes for my NAS so I guess it is the router?
I have set up the router to forward a port to the ssh port 22. It is a Speedport smart 3.

I don't know what could cause the issues with ssh in the router but it worked fine for years and just started about a month ago.

thanks in advance

Edit:

because apparently my setup is not clear:

Router -> switch -> multiple devices connected via wired lan( Windows Pc, raspberry pi, NAS)

None of those devices is connected with wifi the pi and NAS have no wifi adapter.
The Router has a port redirecting to the raspberry and the NAS for port 1234/5 to 22

Within the local network ssh works just fine. When accessing from over the internet it does not,

BUT: ssh password message and login message work fine only after that ssh does not show up the shell for a very long time.

My guess is that the router somehow does not let through some parts of the ssh protocol.

My workaround now would be to set up a website on the pi in order to do a wol what I mainly need it for.

Comment: What happens if you encapsulate the commands in double quotes?  - ie ssh pi@domainname "ls && echo hello";  Also, this sounds like it could either be a connection tracking issue or, more likely, an MTU issue.  Try temporarily setting a smaller MTU for your computer (say 1400) and seeing if the commands stop freezing.  If they do, then we at least know the problem that needs to be tackled.

Comment: @davidgo encapsulating did not change anything. Editing mtu with sudo ip link set eth0 mtu 1400 did work once, so it showed ls and echo, but after several retries it does not work anymore, also rebooting did not help with that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"The Router has a port redirecting to the raspberry and the NAS for port 1234 to 22"*? You **cannot** have port redirection to two *different* internal devices with the *same public* port. You *can* have two internal devices on port 22, but with *different* public port. For example, for the NAS public port 1234 -> internal port 22, and for the RasPI public port 1235 -> internal port 22. If that was the error, I'll make this comment an answer.

Comment: I expect the issue is either to do with your routers connection tracking or the mtu or both.   Are you sure running a web server on the pi will work? If you have an mtu issue it may not.  Another thought - do you have the possibility of setting up a DMZ pointed to the Pi in your router?  There is a small chance this would fix the issue by using a different invocation if NAT.  (You can maintain security by running a firewall on your Pi)

Comment: @Binarus yeah I have it set up correctly, sorry for the misleading info

Comment: @davidgo The website is up and running so that does work. The other points you mentioned I just have to look up first and try out. It is also difficult because I don't have physical access for the week and don't want to kill my pi from ssh completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that we don't know enough about your setup to answer your question. However, some general guidelines:

First, disconnect any network components you don't need for testing, and use reliable cable connections instead of WiFi. That is, turn WiFi off in your router completely. Then connect your RasPI directly to your router using a cable which is known to be good, and disconnect any other device from your router.

In your RasPI's configuration, assign a static IP address to the RasPI (along with static nameserver, gateway and so on), and turn off DHCP in your router. Double check whether the port forwarding in the router points to the right IP address (the one you have assigned manually to the RasPI).

Then repeat the SSH test from the outside. If it works now, you can try to revert the above steps one by one. If it still does not work, try to borrow a router from a friend for a few hours (you could make a delicious pizza for him in exchange, couldn't you?), and test again. If it works with the other router, you have probably identified the culprit.

However, you should do further tests for a while even in case of success, at least if you have usually connected your RasPI to the router via WiFi. I could imagine (though it is not likely) that a neighbor's equipment uses the same WiFi channels as your router and disturbs the communication. In that scenario, I don't have an explanation why it works if you connect to your RasPI when you are at home, but as I said above, we don't know enough about your setup. For example, if you are using a notebook to connect to the RasPI directly via WiFi, that notebook could use other channels than your router, might provide a stronger signal, or might have better reception.

Comment: I have updated the question and will try some of your suggestions, but since I share the router with my roommates and do not own it I don't think an exchange is possible.

Comment: Ok, So I just restarted the router by powering off and on again manually and this seemed to have worked..... This is a bit of embarrassing.